# Wordpress not runing under new dedicated server

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-504

I just moved my installed WordPress from shared hosting (which was working just fine) to dedicate server and I keep getting "500 Internal Server Error" error . I tried deleting .htaccess, renaming plugins folder, increasing memory and nothing worked. What else should I try?

One thing I noticed is that when I change PHP support from "FastCGI 5.4.45" to "Apache 5.4.45" I get "504 Gateway Time-out" error.

Comment: still showing 504 Gateway Time-out. your web server is Nginx.

Comment: yes, I know. So what cause this?

Comment: delete the .htaccess file and set the permalinks to default and test

Comment: I did that now, but nothing happends

Comment: did you change PHP, I still see 504

Comment: just changed it back to "FastCGI 5.4.45" and "500 Internal Server Error" appears

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94994/discussion-between-lucky-chingi-and-boris).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wp-config pointing to the old database server, changing it to local host fixed the site